# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException......again

Tags: php, forms, routes, laravel-5.3

I have an update form and when I save I get this error message

> (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
>
> at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in
>
> RouteCollection.php (line 238)

Here is my form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('products.update', $product->ProductId)}}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
```

and my routes

```
Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products.index');
Route::post('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products.search');
Route::get('products/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('products.create');
Route::post('products/create', 'ProductController@store')->name('products.store');
Route::get('products/{id}', 'ProductController@show')->name('products.show');
Route::get('products/{id}/edit', 'ProductController@edit')->name('products.edit');
Route::post('products/{id}/edit', 'ProductController@update')->name('products.update');
```

The routes list looks fine except the update route whereas other updates routes use PUT|PATCH

> | | POST      | products/{id}/edit  products.update |
>   \Http\Controllers\ProductController@update | web,auth

As far as I can see everything should work so why is the method not updating?

Comment: Could you change `Route::post('products/{id}/edit', ...` to `Route::put('products/{id}/edit', ...` and see what that does?

Answer (score 0):

You declared your route as `POST`.

Then in the form you spoof the `PUT` method.

`POST != PUT`.

The route is not defined to handle the method `PUT`. The method you define is the method that has to be used.